# Is it possible to force a USB port to always deliver 5V in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, power-supply

I made myself a circuit which needs 5 volts of power but I want to draw the power from the USB port while the system runs Linux kernel version 2.6.29.6-smp

I think my USB driver supports power management, but I want to somehow force one port to always deliver out max power so my external circuitry that requires 5 volts to won't mess up due to lack of power.

I wouldn't mind if I disable power management completely across the entire USB system in my computer.

What would be the best way to do this in terms of Linux settings?

Comment: The port should always deliver 5v. Its current output that can vary.

Comment: Also be careful not to draw more than rated current. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power